# HTML 5 Amazon S3 Direct Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am looking for an HTML 5 AJAX library / framework for users to upload files directly to Amazon S3. The goal is to avoid uploading attachments to the web server (as the web server blocks when it transfer them to Amazon). My understanding is that this should be possible using `XDomainRequest`, but I can't figure out how.

I am running ruby-on-rails and wanted to assign the uploaded file a temporary name (using a UUID) that will be posted back to the web server so the file can later be renamed and integrated with paperclip.

Any ideas? Is this something jQuery can handle? Flash isn't an option for this project. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I managed to get a basic post working but am still have issues. I'm not exactly sure what headers are required, or how to encode the Amazon required parameters in the request (can I put them in the request header?). Here is my progress thus far:

```
const XMLHTTPFactories = [
  function () { return new XDomainRequest(); },
  function () { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
  function () { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); },
  function () { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP"); },
  function () { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); },
];

var xhr = null;

for (var i = 0; i < XMLHttpFactories.length; i++) {
    try { xhr = XMLHttpFactories[i](); break; } catch (exception) { continue; }
}

$(this).change(function () {

  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var file = this.files[i];

    xhr.open(settings.method, settings.url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);

    xhr.send(file);
  }
```

**Edit:**

After further updates, I've managed to get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/.
>   Origin http://local.app is
>   not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've uploaded a `crossdomain.xml` file that allows access from the wildcard (*) domain. Not sure how to continue...

**Edit:**

After having done more investigation, I'm starting to think that the JavaScript POST might not be possible to S3. Will I be required to post to an EC2 instance before doing a transfer? I might be able to secure a micro instance, but I'd prefer to go direct to S3 if possible! Thanks!

**Edit:**

I posted the question on the Amazon Forums and haven't received any feedback. For cross references the other post can be found here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=206650#206650.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the other side issue [an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control).  In you case the other side is Amazon S3 server. Unless they mention your domain in that header you won't be able to make any cross-site requests to them.

[Amazon S3 now supports Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html) and you can configure any of your S3 buckets for cross-domain access by adding one or more CORS rules to your bucket. Each rule can specify a domain that should have access to your bucket and a set of HTTP verbs you wish to allow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Any chance you know if I can set the response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on Amazon S3?

Comment: @Kevin I've been researching this. Amazon S3 does not support setting this header on buckets *or* objects. For more information, check out this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=160131). Amazon seems to have zero interest in supporting it in the future, according to their (lack of) response.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. I was actually a 'poster' on that thread and have given up hope.

Comment: CORS is now available on S3 (3.5 years after being requested!)

Answer (score 4):

Today Amazon announces complete support for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in Amazon S3. You can now easily build web applications that use JavaScript and HTML5 to interact with resources in Amazon S3, enabling you to implement HTML5 drag and drop uploads to Amazon S3, show upload progress, or update content.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This would mean that you have to expose your S3 credentials in JavaScript. You don't want that.</strike>

The best solution is to use Paperclip. Yes, you must upload to your server first, but at least its secure.

Nevermind that, check the comments.

Comment: No, you don't. Amazon supports HMAC SHA-2 encoding of the secret key in combination with an expiration token. They allow direct uploads through regular posts (http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html) I just need it to be AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, still not sure how to fix my bugs Ariejan. Anyone else know? See post above!

Answer (score 1):

S3 can host html pages with jquery no problem.
The bucket becomes the server URL.
If you use a tool like S3 Bucket Explorer you can get a URL in one click for any HTML page in a bucket.

Then you can simply use the PUT command in an XMLHttpRequest to upload files.

This is essentially how the JQuery-HTML5-Upload plugin works for Amazon S3 (See their Issue #12).

In fact you can experiment with the Amazon S3 REST API syntax by just plugging it into variables and then using that in conjunction with the XMLHttpRequest open() method.

Peace in the multiverse.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has finally added support for Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) which allows this:

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing.html

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried myself, but they seem to have this working in the jquery-html5-upload plugin

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-html5-upload/issues/detail?id=12

Answer (score 0):

There is a good rails gem called [s3_drect_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) which does exactly what you want out of the box. It's an html5/javascript uploader with support for renaming files.